# jquery mini slider, generate unique id

Tags: php, jquery

On my Joomla site, I am using a jQuery gallery, where there are 2 instances of it.

The problem is that upon hovering on a thumbnail to show as the main image, it shows that image on both galleries.

Here is my code:

**JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".cars-img img").attr("src", jQuery(".img-log img").eq(0).attr("src"));
    jQuery(".img-log img").eq(0).attr("class", "active");
    jQuery(".img-log img").hover(function(){
        jQuery(".cars-img img").attr("src", jQuery(this).attr('src'));
        jQuery(".img-log img").removeAttr("class", "active");
        jQuery(this).attr('class', 'active');
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cars-img">                  
    <img src="big image link" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="img-smol">
    <div class="img-log">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="small image link" alt=""/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because both sliders are using the same classes. I'd suggest that on hover, you find the outer parent first, then target the image, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var container = $('.carmrg');
    var first     = container.find('.img-log img').eq(0);

    container.find('.cars-img img').attr('src', first.attr('src'));
    first.addClass('active');

    $('.img-log img').hover(function(){

        var $self  = $(this);
        var parent = $self.parents('.carmrg');

        parent.find('.cars-img img').attr('src', $self.attr('src'));
        parent.find('.img-log img').removeClass('active');
        $self.addClass('active');
    });

});
```

Note, I've made a few small tweaks and haven't tested this.

You also appear to be using the code you showed in your question twice. Remove both instances and replace with what I've given you.

Let me know the result.

Comment: thank you this works good! but now is small bug, now big images is The same before hover, see demo http://kulinari.ge/4x4/en/cars

Comment: You need to do this in the HTML: `<img src="FIRST IMAGE HERE" alt=""/>`

Comment: I already have this width php <img src="<?php echo $actual_link ?><?php echo $value[0]; ?>" alt=""/>

Comment: can you please add `<?php var_dump($value[0]); ?>`. The images should be different. I don't know how you're setting `$value[0]` though so kind of hard to tell

Comment: For the 2nd slide, try using `<?php echo $value[12]; ?>` instead, as `0` will call the first image

Comment: this is one module, and I use it twice :(

Comment: @GochaGochitashvili - I've updated my code, please try now

Comment: @GochaGochitashvili - Glad it's all working now :)